# Can't get head around parsing nested JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am having a hard time trying to get my head around this here:

so I have the following JSON:

```
"posts": [
{
  "id": 42400,
  "type": "post",
  "url": "http://dummy.com/noticias/2014/06/senado-promulga-emenda-contra-trabalho-escravo-42400/",
  "status": "publish",
  "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit",
  "title_plain": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit",
  "content": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>",
  "excerpt": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>",
  "date": "2014-06-05 16:59:55",
  "modified": "2014-06-05 17:00:42",
  "author": {
    "id": 2,
    "slug": "author",
    "name": "Author",
    "first_name": "Author",
    "last_name": "",
    "nickname": "Author",
    "url": "",
    "description": ""
  },
  "thumbnail_images": {
    "full": {
      "url": "http://dummy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/pec-trabalho-escravo.jpg",
      "width": 585,
      "height": 390
    },
    "thumbnail": {
      "url": "http://dummy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/pec-trabalho-escravo-110x110.jpg",
      "width": 110,
      "height": 110
    },
    "medium": {
      "url": "http://dummy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/pec-trabalho-escravo-230x130.jpg",
      "width": 230,
      "height": 130
    },
    "large": {
      "url": "http://dummy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/pec-trabalho-escravo-585x360.jpg",
      "width": 585,
      "height": 360
    },
    "slider-thumb": {
      "url": "http://dummy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/pec-trabalho-escravo-520x390.jpg",
      "width": 520,
      "height": 390
    }
  }  
},
```

And this is how I am parsing this JSON:

```
NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectNotation options:0 error:&localError];

if (localError != nil ) {
    *error = localError;
    return nil;
}

NSMutableArray *posts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *results = [parsedObject valueForKey:@"posts"];

for (NSDictionary *postDic in results) {

    Data *data = [[Data alloc] init];
    for (NSString *key in postDic) {
        if ([data respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
            [data setValue:[postDic valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
        }
    }

    [posts addObject:data];
}

return posts;
```

What I can't seem to understand is how can I access the first value inside "thumbnail_images", which is "full" and then get its 'url' value.

Comment: You omitted the initial `{` in the JSON listing that marks the start of an "object".  It's important to observe ALL the characters in the JSON string.

Comment: As to how to parse it, peel it like an onion, one layer at a time.  You've got the outer dictionary, then an array, then the inner dictionary which contains several more dictionaries.  Carefully observe the nesting.  The way you're doing it is only valid for fairly "flat" JSON, which the above is not.

Comment: @HotLicks do you suggest a different approach at storing theses items inside the Data.h model ? and yes I omitted the inital { there sorry

Comment: First off, about half the time there's no compelling reason to not simply leave the data as parsed, in arrays and dictionaries.  They are quite simple and reasonably efficient to access.

Comment: How can I separate and visualize the data I am storing in *data: 

    for (NSString *key in postDic) {
        if ([data respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
            [data setValue:[postDic valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
        }
    }

Comment: Use array index notation.

Comment: (`NSString* firstName = parsedObject["posts"][postNum]["author"]["first_name"];`)

Comment: I created an NSArray inside my Data.h model, to store all the values from thumbnail_images and then used valueForKeyPath to access the one value I wanted, is this a good approach/design pattern ? @HotLicks

Comment: There are dozens of different approaches.  The main thing is to not simply rearrange the data because you think you're supposed to.  And don't fall into the trap of believing that something like valueForKeyPath is somehow more "efficient" than doing the obvious sequence of individual operations.  If it's convenient, use it, but don't distort your code to use it.

Comment: (One thing to get over is the belief that you must have a Data.h model or some such.  There's nothing sacred about that vs just keeping an array or dictionary containing the same data.  Use what's convenient and what makes writing the code straight-forward.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JSONObjectWithData` method creates an object that consists of nested `NSArray`s and `NSDIctionary`s.   To extract items of interest you have to drill down into the object, repeatedly extracting arrays and dictionaries until you reach whatever it is that you want.  Using the modern syntax for arrays and dictionaries makes this relatively easy.

Also note that the error return is only valid if the return value from `JSONObjectWithData` is `nil`.

```
NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectNotation options:0 error:&localError];

if ( parsedObject == nil )
{
    *error = localError;
    return nil;
}

NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *posts = parsedObject[@"posts"];

for ( NSDictionary *post in posts )
{
    NSDictionary *thumb = post[@"thumbnail_images"];
    NSDictionary *full  = thumb[@"full"];
    NSString *urlString = full[@"url"];
    NSLog( @"%@", urlString );

    [results addObject:urlString];
}

return [results copy];
```

Comment: I know fully understand how to access nested objects, thanks @user3386109 =)

Answer (score 0):

The key "posts" has an NSArray for it's value, which is your variable named results. Each index of the results array can contain an array or dictionary.

thumbnail_images is at index 1, so you can get it like this `NSDictionary *thumbImages = results[1];`

From here on out, you can access all the nested keys you want like this. So for "full" and then "url": `NSString *url = thumbImages[@"thumbnail_images"][@"full"][@"url"];`

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the object is a dictionary and then traverse through it:

```
for (NSDictionary *postDic in results) {

Data *data = [[Data alloc] init];
for (NSString *key in postDic) {
    if ([data respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(key)]) {
        if ([results[postDic] isMemberOfClass:[NSDictionary class]) {
            // At this point you will get the "full", "thumbnail", etc dictionaries
            NSDictionary *childDict = results[postDic];
            //Now you can just do the same thing once again to get the url value.
        }
        [data setValue:[postDic valueForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }
}

[posts addObject:data];
}
```